# Change style of controls and html in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Using the latest version of MVC, I want to change the style of an item. From reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887072/how-can-i-apply-styling-to-asp-net-mvc-html-textboxfor), I thought I could use this code:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Adresse, new { style="width:1000px;" })
```

But it won't change the style of any element. How can I fix this code?

Comment: If you are using `DisplayNameFor` then you probably need to make sure the `[Display( Name = "name")]` attribute exsits on your model property `Adresse`

Comment: I have it, can i change the style of this ?

Comment: Then you can give it a CSS class then add this class to the control and write you styles for this class in a stylesheet

Comment: "Give it a CSS class" Where do i add the CSS and what to write exactly @zgood ?

Comment: I went ahead and made an answer. comment on that if you have any questions about this approach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think `DisplayNameFor` renders any HTML elements so adding html attributes to the control won't work.

I would wrap your control with a `span` and add a CSS class, then add that class to your stylesheet where you can write and manage your styles there.

Something like this:

`<span class="display-name">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Adresse)<span>`

Then in your CSS stylesheet add your new class there:

```
.display-name{
   display:inline-block;
   border: 1px solid #ff0000;
   background-color:#eee;
   font-size:15px;
   /*add more styles ...*/
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty much the answer, also i was trying to use the `width` but i realized the right MVC style property is `min-width` , but thats just a detail.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this is accomplished by using the `htmlAttributes` property which is just an anonymous object that contains your preferred styles, just like you have used in your example.

The issue here however is that you are currently attempting to use this with the `DisplayNameFor` helper as opposed to one that rendered an actual element such as `TextBoxFor`, `TextAreaFor` or similar.

The `DisplayNameFor` helper on it's own will simply render the actual name of the property that you are targeting.

Answer (score -1):

Practically the same answer just with some more notes.

use this :
`@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Publishers[0].pub_name, new { @style="width: 1000px" })`
notice the space between the `:` and `1000px`. Avoid using semi-colons if you have only one attribute in style.

Comment: DisplayNameFor function, sorry

Comment: Why don't you use `@LabelFor()` ?

Comment: I agree the space between `:` and `1000px` looks better, but I don't think it prevents the style from rendering. `width:1000px;` and `width: 1000px;` are the same

Comment: Also you don't need `@style` for the style attribute. the `@` is really only used for the `class` attribute because `class` is a reserved word.

Comment: Here is an example I used in one of my applications :
`@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.@params[0].data[0].passwd, new { @class = "form-control" ,placeholder = "Mot de Passe", @style = "color: darkgray; width: 200px;"})` 
This actually works fine.